# swiftUI Synchronous issue with running a function before I have calculated the data for the ZStack element

Tags: swiftui, synchronous

I am using SwiftUI but have a conceptual problem.

I have edited down my code for (hopefully to fully explain the issue )

I want to do some calculations after the button is pressed AFTER which I want to plot the graph.

I am using minX as the bogus result of calculations.

Firstly, note that I have a file (called myGlobal.swift) the contents of which are:

```
import Foundation
class myGlobalVariables: ObservableObject
{
    @Published var minX     :Double =  99999
}
```

The value of this in the getLineChartDataSet = 9999
(from the Global file)
Before I press the button

This changed after I press the button to 222.222 in Mohrs2DCalc func
But of course I have already run myLineChartSwiftUI before I pressed the button,
But want to run myLineChartSwiftUI only AFTER I have pressed the button

```
import SwiftUI
import Charts
struct PricipalStresses2D: View {

 @ObservedObject var input = myGlobalVariables()
var body: some View
{
    
    ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: true)
    {
        VStack(spacing: -10)
        {


                Button(action: {
                    self.CheckInputs()
                })
                {
                        Text("Calculations Before Plot")
            }.padding(50)
            
            
                  myLineChartSwiftUI()  //use frame to change the graph size within your SwiftUI view
                      .frame(alignment: .center)
                      .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        }
    }
}

func CheckInputs()
{
    //Assume all inputs are OK
        self.Mohrs2DCalc()
}


func Mohrs2DCalc()
{
    let minX = 222.222 // Just to set it as if we had calculated it
    self.input.minX = minX
    print("Mohrs circle minX = \(self.input.minX)")
}



struct myLineChartSwiftUI : UIViewRepresentable
{
    let lineChart = LineChartView()
    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<myLineChartSwiftUI>) -> LineChartView {
        setUpChart()
        return lineChart
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: LineChartView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<myLineChartSwiftUI>) {
    }
    func setUpChart() {
        
        //lineChart.noDataText = "No Data Available"
        let dataSets = [getLineChartDataSet()]
        let data = LineChartData(dataSets: dataSets)
        //data.setValueFont(.systemFont(ofSize: 7, weight: .light))
        lineChart.data = data
    }
    func getChartDataPoints(sessions: [Int], accuracy: [Double]) -> [ChartDataEntry] {
        var dataPoints: [ChartDataEntry] = []
        for count in (0..<sessions.count) {
            dataPoints.append(ChartDataEntry.init(x: Double(sessions[count]), y: accuracy[count]))
        }
        return dataPoints
    }
    func getLineChartDataSet() -> LineChartDataSet {
        print("In getLineChartDataSet, minX = ", myGlobalVariables.self.init().minX) // This works fine
        
        let dataPoints = getChartDataPoints(sessions: [0,1], accuracy: [0.0,10.0])  // sessions = x, accuracy = y
        let set = LineChartDataSet(entries: dataPoints, label: "DataSet")
        set.lineWidth = 0
        //set.circleRadius = 4
        //set.circleHoleRadius = 2
        let color = ChartColorTemplates.vordiplom()[4]
        set.setColor(color)
        //set.setCircleColor(color)
        
// Got to set the xMin and xMax from the global to obtain it here
 
        
        return set
    }
}

} //View
    
    
struct PricipalStresses2D_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    PricipalStresses2D()
}
}
```

Your help will be appreciated,
TIA, Phil.

Comment: It's simply part of the View within the body and it executes it procedurally (ie before the calculations are undertaken). If I call the line draw function after the calculations, I don't see how I can place them on the screen?

Comment: I guess an auxiliary question (as this is my 1st SwiftUI program)

How can I set the vale of xMin which is defined in
myGlobalVariables.swift

In the Mohrs2DCalc() func

So I can then obtain this value in
getLineChartDataSet func

Again, appreciate anyone who looks at this

Phil.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Your answer and Binding sorted out my Problem. Again, many thanks:-)